# How can I place multiple copies of the same image class next to each other in CSS?

Tags: html, css, game-development

I am trying to make a flappy bird type game where there will be a row of identical spikes on the bottom of the page. I copy and pasted the image for the spikes 20 times but now I want to use CSS to place all the spike images right next to each other and be on the bottom of the page. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    <img class = 'spike1' src = 'spike.png'>
```

Comment: With only CSS isnetad fo a script like JS you need to use `background-image` and `background-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex?

```css
.spikes { display: flex }
.spikes img { height: 50px; width: 50px }
```

```html
<div class="spikes">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
  <img src="spike.png">
</div>
```